# Create form with round corners

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm using NetBeans, and I have a blank `JFrame`. The `JFrame` is literally empty. I want this `JFrame` to have round corners.

How can I do that?

Comment: By “form”, do you mean an [undecorated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated%28boolean%29) and [shaped](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setShape%28java.awt.Shape%29) frame? If so, I can turn this comment into an answer.

Comment: haha yes, thats exactly what I mean.

Comment: Are you talking about AWT or Swing? Or something else entirely?

Comment: well I think its swing. I opened netbeans, selected file - new project - java application. created it, and then right clicked on the node in the tree and said new - jframe form. that form. then I did the setVisble(true); and it displays. but I also said in the froperties of the form that it is undecorated. so its just a blank form. if I run then its just the blank form without anything. I just want to make the sharp corners round. so that it looks nice. then I'm going to do the rest of the functionality.

Comment: Your question was not clear so I edited it. According to the above answer I took it that by form you meant a `JFrame` (Please note that I edited your question to be more clear).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want rounded corners, then you want a shaped frame. You can achieve that by calling [`Frame.setShape`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setShape%28java.awt.Shape%29). Quoting from its documentation:

> The following conditions must be met to set a non-null shape:
>
> - The `PERPIXEL_TRANSPARENT` translucency must be supported by the underlying system
> - The window must be undecorated (see [setUndecorated(boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated%28boolean%29) and [`Dialog.setUndecorated(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setUndecorated%28boolean%29))
> - The window must not be in full-screen mode (see [`GraphicsDevice.setFullScreenWindow(Window)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html#setFullScreenWindow%28java.awt.Window%29))

The second of these points, an undecorated frame, corresponds to a part of your original question which was rephrased in a subsequent edit: It will give you

> No windows like stuff, just the form, with no exit button, nothing.

Comment: Set the `shape` property with code `new RoundRectangle2D.Double(100, 100, 800, 600, 50, 50)` in the IDE. In general `setUndecorated(true);` must precede `setShape(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(100, 100, 800, 600, 50, 50));`.

Comment: Sorry, I have no Idea whats going on. I set everything right as you said and the link but I dont get it ti be round...

Comment: what does each number stand for?

Comment: @Bebbie7: read [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/RoundRectangle2D.Double.html#RoundRectangle2D.Double%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double%29) for the `RoundRectangle2D.Double` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

try this. its work :)

```
yourframe.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 180));
yourframe.setUndecorated(true);
yourframe.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
               @Override
                public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                    setShape(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), 80, 80));
                }
            });
```